# std::bad_alloc in a c++ vector

Tags: c++

I am coping a float processed data to an std vector and I am adding a 0 every 3 values so I could get a frame of 4 values. The size of the vector is less than the maximum data.max_size() = 1 073 741 823.
the total size of the vector is data.size()=55 000 000.

The problem is that when I run my App and especially when saving the data to the new vector the app stops automatically and I get **std::bad_alloc** Error.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue? I am using QTcreator, the app runs in 32bit and I get the processed data from an inherited public class. **DATA_getAllMeasurments()[i]->DPacket.DATA_Packet** is the data vector.

```
  void FileGenerate::GeneratePDOfile(uint8 i, std::string  path){

    std::vector <float>data;

    int size = DATA_getAllMeasurments()[i]->DPacket.DATA_Packet.size();
    int newsize= (size *4)/3; 
    unsigned int m =0;
    
    for (int k=0; k<newsize ; k++){
        if (k%4==0)
            data.push_back(0.0);
        else            
            data.push_back(DATA_getAllMeasurments()[i]->DPacket.DATA_Packet[m++]);              
        
    }    
    std::string path2 = path + "/Measurement" +std::to_string(i+1)+".pdo";
    std::ofstream myFile (path2, std::ios::out | std::ios::binary);
    myFile.write((char *)&(data[0]),data.size() *sizeof (float));
    myFile.close();
    data.clear();
    }
```

Comment: How much ram do you have?  50M floats needs about 420MB.

Comment: 420MB of contiguous addresses.

Comment: I have 8 Gb ram, there is more than 2 Gb free in ram but the app still closing automatically

Comment: Note - if you build as 64 bit (which assuming this is on a normal PC and not some embedded device should be the norm) then you are much more likely to be able to find 420MB of contiguous address range. Its likely that you've got virtual address fragmentation in your 32 bit process.

Comment: Consider using `data.reserve(newsize);` to avoid repeatedly reallocating the storage.

Comment: `max_size()` is pretty much useless. All it tells you is that if you try to create more elements than `max_size()` you will surely fail. It does not tell you how many elements you can, in fact, create.

Comment: @mohamedbousselmi *I have 8 Gb ram* -- And you are wasting half of it by running a 32-bit program.  If you want to take advantage of all the RAM, the program must be 64-bit.  You could have 128 Gb RAM, a 32-bit program can only use 4GB of that memory..  Also, as others mentioned, the memory must be in contiguous space, not bits and pieces that just add up to what you claim is 2Gb.

Comment: Thank you very much :)
I think that the best solution now is to split the vector into two or more vectors and then write them in the file, if you think that there is a better solution please recommend it to me

Answer (score 1):

The function [`std::vector::max_size()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/max_size) reports what maximum size is supported by the **standard library**.

It is evaluated at **compile time**, and does not report the runtime capabilities of the system your program might be running on.

That said, it is likely that your system did not have enough contiguous memory to allocate the required space.  Even if your OS is reporting enough "free space", `std::vector` is designed to require **contiguous** space.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer :) 
I opened the task manager in real-time while the app is running, So actually there is more than 2Gb of free space in Ram but the App still crashes and closes automatically after a while.

Comment: @mohamedbousselmi I suspect that you would benefit from reading about the difference between "contiguous space" and "total free space".  Your task manager is not telling you the size of the largest contiguous block of available space.

Comment: yes you are right the problem is that in the memory there is no contiguous space, that's why it automatically close the App 
I am gonna try first by splitting the vector into more vectors and write them into a file one by one, If you have a better solution please let me know ;) 
Thank you

Answer (score 1):

By constantly growing your vector, you are fragmenting the addressing space of your process, and in a 32 bit process that is a limited resource.

Fortunately, there is a simple solution - just call `data.reserve (new size)` before entering your`for` loop.  Chances are, the code will then work.